# Take Screen Shot in Background using Selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium

I am Running the Script in I.E. browser.
I have a problem, when I run the script and try to do other task on my PC the script run successfully BUT its capture the screen shots of the current window not the one in which the script is running I.e IE browser

How can I Capture the screen shot of the browser in which the script is running ?
I am using following command for capturing the screen

```
  selenium.captureScreenshot("D:/screen_" + System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg");
```

I want to execute the script and take screen shot but at the same time I want to do my other task. After successfully execution i just want to check my screen shots.

Any Suggestion ?

Thanks 
Dushyant

Comment: You could try running selenium as another user on the system and kick it off automatically. I run my unit tests using Jenkins at work on windows box. It runs as a regular windows user with IE configured loosely and can work around some of these issues. The catch is that if IE hangs with a prompt, it can stop all unit tests from continuing after that.

Comment: That is a awesome suggestion. I will surely try this and will check if I can use my script effectively in different user. Thanks Man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In current user session, If you move focus on different window then It will capture current window.

Solution - 
Use window focus command prior to screenshot command but it might disturbing as you are working on some other windows and its moved to other window

Other solutions - 
As Lucas mentions - Run on different user session
Or run on different machine/VM
Or keep machine ideal

Comment: I will also try this as my script is long. It take screen shots after every 3-4 mins. So at least i can work 3-4 mins and then again switch back from Script window to my currently working window. Thanks for the  suggestion.